# What does $scheme in site_url function do?

Tags: site-url

Could someone tell me what the `$scheme` precisely does in the `site_url` function? What does it provide and how to use it? Of course I have read the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url), but since I am not a native English speaker, nor a native coder, I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php site_url( $path, $scheme ); ?>
```

**Parameters**

> $path: (optional) Path to be appended to the site url.
>
> $scheme: (optional) Context for the protocol for the url returned. Setting $scheme will override the default context. Allowed values are 'http', 'https', 'login', 'login_post', 'admin', or 'relative'.

It simply overrides the default parameters in URL.

For example if you have a website URL like `http://www.example.com` (without https) and you want to add https URL on a specific link instead of http, then you use `$scheme` parameter.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Also could you explain how this can be used in an if statement? I found a code like "if $scheme == "login"  do this.. To do an if statement do i first need to get the scheme value?

Comment: No you can't do that. You cannot check parameter value outside the function. What you probably saw is some local variable checking for a condition.

Comment: Related question: Does anyone know, could `$scheme` and `site_url` be combined with `wpmu_new_blog` to make all new multisite sites https by default? See my question here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313417/make-default-new-sites-https-multisite